# Declare an array of queues

Tags: c#, arrays, syntax, array-initialization

What is the language grammatical problem in my code?
I want to declare an  array of queues. Is this the right way to declare and use them?

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Queue<int>[] downBoolArray = new Queue<int>[8]();
        downBoolArray[0].Enqueue(1);
    }
```

Comment: As the error tells you, you cannot put the parentheses after the closing `]` - though removing the parentheses (`new Queue<int>[8]`) will give you an array of `null` references

Comment: Oh!! I added the error I got! Thanks.

Comment: Your array consist of null object. First instantiate the queue's in the array.

Comment: `Queue<int>[] downBoolArray = new Queue<int>[8];
downBoolArray[0] = new  Queue<int>();
downBoolArray[0].Enqueue(1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first problem is a syntax error: `new Queue<int>[8]()` should be `new Queue<int>[8]`.

Once declared with the correct syntax, when you attempt to use an element of the array (`downBoolArray[0].Enqueue(1)`) you will encounter a [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/397817)  because array elements [initialise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300089/397817) to their [default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null) which in the case of a reference type is `null`.

You could instead initialise your array with non-null seed values using a single line of LINQ:

```
Queue<int>[] downBoolArray = Enumerable.Range(1,8).Select(i => new Queue<int>()).ToArray();
```

The arguments to `Range` specify that we need 8 'entries' in our sequence; the `Select` statement creates a new `Queue<int>` for each item; and the `ToArray` call outputs our sequence as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize each element in your array

```
void Main()
{
    Queue<int>[] downBoolArray =new Queue<int>[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < downBoolArray.Length; i++)
        downBoolArray[i] = new Queue<int>();
    downBoolArray[0].Enqueue(1);
}
```

Comment: please add what your code is doing and why, otherwise it wouldn't add much.

Comment: Thanks A lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You mean `downBoolArray.Length;` instead of `downBoolArray.Count();`

Comment: @Ravenix : Added the explanation

Comment: @Dennis_E : Length will also work

Comment: @Dennis_E An array is an IEnumerable<T>, so both Length and Count() work in this case.

Comment: `Count()` also works, but that is not the point. `Count()` does unnecessary work. We always use `.Length` when accessing the number of items in an array.

Comment: @Dennis_E:Updated the answer

Comment: @Dennis_E In case the the underlying collection implements `ICollection<T>`  which array does, it is not more costly to call `Count()` than `Length`

Comment: @Magnus Still doesn't matter. `Count()` still does an unnecessary cast. We use `.Length` to access the number of items in an array. There's no reason to use `.Count()`. It's weird.

Answer (score -2):

You've created an array of **null** values.

What you want is something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {

    var queues = new Queue<int>[8];

    // Possibly some other stuff

    // Initialise all values
    for (var i = 0; i < queues.Length; i++) {
        // Accounting for maybe already sporadically initialising values
        queues[i] = (queues[i]) ?? new Queue<int>();

    }
    // Do whatever

}
```

Comment: That `foreach` loop is not going to work.